# python list comprehension with two functions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

OK, I can do this:

```
[i for i in range(100) if i > 10 if i < 50]
```

or I can do this:

```
[i for i in range(100) if i > 10 and i < 50]
```

BUT, if I try this:

```
def is_big(number):
    number > 10
def is_small(number):
    number < 50
```

I get:

```
[i for I in range(100) if is_big(I) and is_small(I)]
[]
[i for I in range(100) if is_big(I) if is_small(I)]
[]
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from your functions.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33222168/198633

Answer (score 0):

Your functions must return boolean results

```
def is_big(number):
    return number > 10

def is_small(number):
    return number < 50

print [i for i in range(100) if is_big(i) and is_small(i)]
```

Comment: No need for if. `return number > 10` or `return number < 50`

Comment: You're right. More pythonic like this. Thanks (answer modified)